# Why does query.where() function treat every condition as an "$and"?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var schema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  nbPages: Number,
  language: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['en', 'fr', 'es']
  },
  kind: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['action', 'drama', 'comedy', 'detective', 'love']
  },
});

var getKindConditions = function () {
  return {
    $or: [
      // I can read anything in english...
      {
        language: 'en'
      },
      // ...but would prefer love stories in french...
      {
        language: 'fr',
        kind: 'love'
      },
      // ...or comedy ones in spanish.
      {
        language: 'es',
        kind: 'comedy'
      },
    ]
  };
}

schema.methods.findBooksToRead = function(callback) {
  var query = this.model('Books').find({
    // Initial conditions.
    $or: [
      // I can read big books in english...
      {
        nbPages: { $gt: 300 },
        language: 'en'
      },
      // ...but I'm still learning french and spanish.
      {
        nbPages: { $lte: 300 },
        language: { $or: ['fr', 'es'] }
      }
    ]
  });

  var kindConditions = getKindConditions();

  // Additionnal conditions.
  query.where(kindConditions);

  query.exec(callback);
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Books', schema);
```

With this example, I'm screwed. The `$or` operator I add when I set the `query.where(kindConditions)` will overwrite the `$or` operator I had placed within the `this.model('Books').find(...)`.

Should it be right for the Mongoose `where` function to consider all new elements as `$and`?

Here's my workaround (push all new conditions in a `$and` logical query operator:

```
schema.methods.findBooksToRead = function(callback) {
  var conditions = {
    $and: []
  };

  // Initial conditions.
  conditions.$all.push({
    $or: [
      // I can read big books in english...
      {
        nbPages: { $gt: 300 },
        language: 'en'
      },
      // ...but I'm still learning french and spanish.
      {
        nbPages: { $lte: 300 },
        language: { $or: ['fr', 'es'] }
      }
    ]
  });

  var kindConditions = getKindConditions();

  // Additionnal conditions.
  conditions.$all.push(kindConditions);

  var query = this.model('Books').find(conditions);

  query.exec(callback);
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Books', schema);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's appropriate for Mongoose to do that.  You're running into an issue between two (somewhat) mutually-exclusive styles for constructing queries: with [QueryBuilder](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query-js) and without.

In the callback style (that is, not QueryBuilder), there's no need for `query.exec` and you can just pass the callback directly:

```
var query = this.model('Books').find(conditions, callback);
```

This query will execute immediately.  If however you don't give it a callback, you get a Query object back which has the QueryBuilder interface and you can progressively *build up* your query with operations like `where`, `all`, `and`, `or`, etc.

```
var query = this.model('Books').find();
query.where({ something: true }); // This must match
query.where({ somethingElse: false }); // AND this must match
query.exec();
```

Your second example works, and it works better because it's consistent in the style in which the criteria is applied.  You could do it with the other style (using `query.or` and removing it from your conditions object), just understand that executing functions on QueryBuilder is modifying/building the query up with each call to one of its functions.

Also, `where` is used for chaining on a path.  It's taking your object and providing a shortcut for checking against your criteria.  If you write something like this, it'll be more clear:

```
query.where('language').equals('en');
```

So: stick with your second bit of code (perhaps using a new `where` call for each item in the array instead of your top level `$and`), or rework the former to exclude the query operations on your `find` call and build it up using `query.or` instead.

Comment: Typo `query.where('language').equals('en');`

Answer (score 0):

I tried rebuilding with `query.or` and QueryBuilder but overwriting and merging of `$or` conditions can happen as well.

### `query.where` (`$or` are overwritten)

As @adam-terlson suggest, it's not a good idea to mixed up the method but, as we can, it's interesting to see what's happen when we do it.

```
var query = this.model('Books').find();

// First "or" conditions.
query.where({
  $or: [
    { nbPages: { $gt: 300 }, language: 'en' },
    { nbPages: { $lte: 300 }, language: { $or: ['fr', 'es'] } }
  ]
});

// Second "or" conditions.
query.where({
  $or: [
    { language: 'en' },
    { language: 'fr', kind: 'love' },
    { language: 'es', kind: 'comedy' }
  ]
});

query.exec(callback);
```

#### Results

In my `query._conditions`, I can see that the `where` function as **overwrite** my first `$or` conditions.

```
{
  $or: [
    { language: 'en' },
    { language: 'fr', kind: 'love' },
    { language: 'es', kind: 'comedy' }
  ]
}
```

### `query.or` (`$or` are merged)

```
var query = this.model('Books').find();

// First "or" conditions.
query.or([
  { nbPages: { $gt: 300 }, language: 'en' },
  { nbPages: { $lte: 300 }, language: { $or: ['fr', 'es'] } }
]);

// Second "or" conditions.
query.or([
  { language: 'en' },
  { language: 'fr', kind: 'love' },
  { language: 'es', kind: 'comedy' }
]);

query.exec(callback);
```

#### Results

In my `query._conditions`, I can see that the `or` function as **merge** my `$or` conditions.

```
{
  $or: [
    { nbPages: { $gt: 300 }, language: 'en' },
    { nbPages: { $lte: 300 }, language: { $or: ['fr', 'es'] } },
    { language: 'en' },
    { language: 'fr', kind: 'love' },
    { language: 'es', kind: 'comedy' }
  ]
}
```

### `query.and` (`$or` are appended)

So if you need 2 or more distinct sets of `$or` conditions, you can't build it in the query as you go. You have to get all your `$or` conditions together then use the `and` function.

```
var query = this.model('Books').find();
var orConditions = [];

// First "or" conditions.
orConditions.push({
  $or: [
    { nbPages: { $gt: 300 }, language: 'en' },
    { nbPages: { $lte: 300 }, language: { $or: ['fr', 'es'] } }
  ]
});

// Second "or" conditions.
orConditions.push({
  $or: [
    { language: 'en' },
    { language: 'fr', kind: 'love' },
    { language: 'es', kind: 'comedy' }
  ]
});

query.and(orConditions);

query.exec(callback);
```